# How to run cron job every one hour and 10 min

Tags: linux, cron

I did the following:

```
0 */10 * * * {CMD}
```

but it worked until midnight and didn't continue the next day. Can someone please suggest something?

Comment: do you mean every 70 mins?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use this:

```
10 * * * * {CMD}
```

which means start new job at 10 minutes of every hour: 1:10, 2:10, ...

If you want to start at 1:10, 2:20, 3:30, ..., then you will need to write a lot of manual rules, each starting at those times (or write your own scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

Every Hour but on 10th minute eg. 1:10, 2:10, 3:10 etc.

```
https://crontab.guru/#10_*_*_*_*
```

It works like charm :)